# Right algorithm for finding largest prime factor

Tags: python, algorithm, prime-factoring

I am trying to find out the largest prime factor of any number. I am doing the program for this problem in python, but there seems to be something wrong with the algorithm that I am following. It seems to fall into an infinite loop. The program goes like this:

```
def prime(n):
  i=0;
  while(n!=2):
    for i in range(2,n):
        if(n%i==0):
            prime(n/i);
        else:
            continue;
    print("The highest prime factor is: "),n;

print("Enter a number to find its highest prime factor");
n=input();
prime(n);
```

Just point out what are the problems here and also mention if there are any other better algorithm than this one for solving this.

Comment: fix the indentation of your code and make sure that you do not mix up whitespace and tabs.

Comment: while(n!=2):   When will n be equal to 2? You are not changing n anywhere.

Comment: As (n/i) is used in each step and when that's returned to n in the (def prime)value of n is going to decrease. That is why I had given n!=2@AbhishekBansal. Is this not allowed in python?

Comment: That's fine, but then when it comes out of the recursive call n is n*i as before.

Comment: In that part should I approach like this n=n/i and then call as prime(n)@doctorlove

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT : It feels like I can't manage to be clear without some code, so here it is, with a few modification from yours :

```
def prime(n):
  i=2
  while (n%i != 0 and i < n):
    i += 1
  if (i < n):
    return prime (n/i)
  else:
    print("The highest prime factor is: "),n

print("Enter a number to find its highest prime factor")
n=input()
prime(n)
```

However, your algorithm is not very efficient. For example, you might consider using Pollard's Rho if you want something better and not long to code.
And even if you want to stick with your idea, you shouldn't do your divisibility tests like this. You may want to run an Erathostene sieve first to only test divisibility by prime factors. Or even only remember the last divisor you found in order to restart the algorithm from there, not from 2.

For example, a little bit better code would be :

```
def prime(n,a):
  i = a
  while (n%i != 0 and i*i < n):
    i += 1
  if (i*i < n):
    return prime (n/i, i)
  else:
    print("The highest prime factor is: "),n

print("Enter a number to find its highest prime factor")
n=input()
prime(n,2)
```

Comment: That still gets stuck in a loop

Comment: Even if I'm using n!=1,the problem persists

Comment: That's what I'm asking@doctorlove,how to come out of that loop?

Comment: Ok@Traklon, the first code that you gave among the last 2 works

Comment: @Traklon in your second code you will need to check up to n/2. For example, with n = 10, answer should be 5, but your loop will stop at i = 4.

Comment: That's because the code will divide n by 2 first because 10 = 5*2. So it will stop at i = 3 for n = 5.

Answer (score 1):

My solution is rather simple and deals well with huge numbers that would cause memory error in most of the solutions above.

```
import math

def prime(n):
    for x in range(2, int(math.sqrt(n)) + 1):
        if n % x == 0:
            print n / x
            return prime(n / x)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    prime(898563214300)
```

The last printed number is the largest prime factor.

Answer (score 1):

Avoiding recursive calls:

```
def largest_prime_factor(number):
  if number == 1:
    return 1

  test = 2
  while number > 1:
    if number % test == 0:
      number /= test
    else:
      test += 1

  return test
```

Answer (score 0):

I can stop your code getting tuck in a loop as follows. 

The main problem with the stuck in a loop is the `while(n!=2)` (or 1 or whatever) is that you don't change `n`.

*Note - it still won't give you prime numbers*

```
def prime(n):
  i=0
  if(n==2):
    print "The highest prime factor is 2"
    return
  for i in range(2,n):
      if(n%i==0):
          prime(n/i)
      else:
          continue
  print("The highest prime factor is: "),n

print("Enter a number to find its highest prime factor");
n=input()
prime(n)
```

Search SO with '[python] primes' for lots of ways to do this properly.

Answer (score 0):

One simple (but highly inefficient) approach without recursion would be:
(please excuse my python syntax).

Assuming isPrime(k) is a function that returns true if k is prime. It can be implemented using sieve of Erastosenes.

```
def prime(n):
  i=0;
  largestPrimeFactor = -1;
  for i in range(2,n/2):
     if( isPrime(i) && n%i==0 ) :
         largestPrimeFactor = i;
  print("The highest prime factor is: "),largestPrimeFactor
```

Comment: Where are u taking a number as input@Abhishek Bansal and is isPrime any predefined function or the function prime that you taken is same as isPrime?

Comment: I had skipped the input part for simplicity. isPrime is another function that you will have to implement. There are numerous ways of doing so. The sieve of Erastothenes is considered one the most efficient ways. Checkout http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114167/checking-if-a-number-is-a-prime-number-in-python

Comment: Ok@Abhishek ..I will definitely try out

Answer (score 0):

consider this code snippet in C, this is a very efficient algorithm for finding the largest prime factor of a number.

The functions are self-explanatory.

```
int isPrime(long long int n)
{
    long long int i;
    for(i=2;i*i<=n;i++)
        if(n%i==0)
            return 0;
    return 1;
}

long long int findLargestPrimeFactor(long long int n)
{
    long long int counter=2;
    while(n!=1)
    {
        if(isPrime(n))
            return n;
        while(n%counter==0)
            n/=counter;
        counter++;
   }
   return counter-1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code can be further optimized as shown below, its written in php but the logic seems fair

```
for($div=2;$div<=sqrt($n);$div++)
{
    if($n%$div==0)
    {
        $n = $n/$div;
        $div--;
    }
}
```

by taking the sq root , you avoid the uncecessary looping.