# Why does prime number checker say 9 is a prime number?

Tags: python, primes

```
print "Type a number"
num = int(raw_input("> "))

if num % 2 == 0:
    print "This is not a prime number"

else:
    print "This is a prime number"
```

When I type '9' it says it's a prime number, which it isn't:

```
Type a number
> 9
This is a prime number
```

Is my code too simple? Is there something it doesn't check?

Comment: Because this is not a prime number checker.  You're basically checking even or odd, and 9 is odd.

Comment: Your program asks "is this number divisible by 2? If not, it's prime". That's why it counts 9 as a prime. Perhaps look into the [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) for a simple prime checker?

Comment: Your code doesn't check prime numbers, it checks if a number is even or odd.

Comment: Your program is only checking if the number inputted is divisible by 2 or not. Which actually checks for even number. Not prime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To check if number is prime you have to validate is it devisible by any number in range [2, sqrt(n)].

Following code does exactly the same:

```
import math

def is_prime(n):
    for i in range(2, int(math.sqrt(n))+1):
        if n % i == 0:
            return False
    return True
```

This method is good for small number, but if n is real big number then you need something faster. And in this case you can use [Miller–Rabin primality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller%E2%80%93Rabin_primality_test) test which checks primality with a certain probability.

Comment: Why `int(math.sqrt(n))+1)`?

Comment: range(x, y) returns interval [x, y) (excluding y) but you also need to check value sqrt(n) so you can say range(x, y+1) and now y will included into validation too.

Comment: But why square root of the number in question?

Comment: Because you dont have to validate all numbers from 2 to n. If n is not prime number and one of its dividers is greater than sqrt(n) then another one is smaller, so trying dividers from 2 till sqrt(n) you may find all dividers of number n (even greated than sqrt(n)).

Comment: Thanks, I understand now.

Answer (score 4):

You're only checking if it is an even number, by checking if it is divisible by 2. But 9 is divisible by 3 so you need to check that also. The easiest way would be to check all numbers up to the square root of the number you're checking for primality.

Answer (score 4):

All you are doing here is checking whether or not a number is evenly divisible by 2. Since 9 / 2 = 4.5, it's not evenly divisible by 2 thus going to the else clause.

Here is a condensed, working version of what you probably want:

```
def is_prime(a):
    return all(a % i for i in xrange(2, a))
```

Answer (score 1):

You are checking if a given number is even or not, and 9 is not even so your code prints out "This is a prime number"

Please take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114167/checking-if-a-number-is-a-prime-number-in-python) Stackoverflow question for a detailed explanation on how to check for prime numbers using Python.