# My code works fine but every time the input is a prime number it keeps on printing "This is a prime number." over and over. How do I stop this?

Tags: python, python-3.x

My code is a PYTHON program that identifies if a number is prime or not. When I entered 45 however, it said that 45 was a prime, even though 45 isn't a prime number. Also, every time I run the program, it prints 'Sorry, the number you have entered is not prime.' or 'The number is indeed prime!' multiple times, instead of once. How do I make it print the output statements once and how can fix the program so that it says 45 IS NOT a prime number.

```
n = eval(input("Enter a number to find if that number is prime: "))
a = 2
while n > a:
    if ((n % a) == 0) & (a != n):
       print('Sorry, the number you have entered is not prime.')
    break
    else:
       print('The number you have entered is indeed prime!')
```

Comment: You shouldn't be using `eval` to parse integers, use `int` instead, while it's not really important in a learning example I'd suggest you [read Why is using `eval` a bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/why-is-using-eval-a-bad-practice) for when it is important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has some issues. To start with, you're never updating `a`, so you only ever check if the number `n` is even.

Once you fix that, you have two indentation problems. The first is that the `break` line needs to be inside the body of the `if` statement. Indent it more so that it's inside the `if` block.

The second indentation issue is more subtle. If you leave the `else` where it is, it will print out that the number is prime every time you test a potential factor that doesn't divide the number. That's both unhelpful (since it prints a lot) and wrong (since it says the number is prime even if it will later find a factor and say it's not prime). You can fix this by unindenting the `else` line so that it is lined up with the `while` statement. Using an `else` after a loop is an obscure bit of Python syntax. The body of the `else` only runs if the condition of the loop fails. It gets skipped if the loop exits due to a `break` statement.

Here's all of those necessary fixes together:

```
while n > a:
    if ((n % a) == 0) & (a != n):
        print('Sorry, the number you have entered is not prime.')
        break                                # indent this line more!
    a += 1                          # increment a, so you don't keep checking 2 over and over
else:                                        # unindent this line (and the next line too)
    print('The number you have entered is indeed prime!')
```

There are some other things that could be improved in your code, though they aren't causing it to run incorrectly. I'd recommend using `int` instead of `eval` to parse your number, and I'd use the logical-and operator `and` instead of the bitwise-and operator `&` in the `if` statement (though actually you don't need either, since the `a != n` check is redundant, as the loop would have already ended if it was true).

Comment: @NickA: The bitwise-and operator actually works OK for logical-and as long as its arguments are actually `bool` instances. That's because `bool` is a subtype of `int`, with `True` equal to `1` and `False` equal to `0`. So I didn't fix that in the updated version of the code, just mentioned it later.

Comment: @Blckknght Ah, so it's only important to avoid it if any parts of the condition aren't `bool`s?

Comment: @NickA: Yes. The `and` operator will call `bool` on its first argument as necessary to asses its truth value. The `&` operator will not, since it expects to be working on numbers. `1 and 2` is truthy (it will be `2`, due to `and`'s short-circuiting behavior), but `1 & 2` is `0`, which is falsey.

Answer (score 2):

Because you are printing it every time. If you want to break after finding/not finding the prime number, indent one more level for the `break`.

Also, this does not calculate prime numbers. It calculates if its even number.

Follow the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114167/checking-if-a-number-is-a-prime-number-in-python)

Comment: Inside the loop, neither `n` nor `a` is changing. So, the loop keeps on going printing something every time.