# Which is the most pythonic way for writing a prime number function using for and while loop?

Tags: python, for-loop, while-loop, primes

I am about to execute a function which aim is to return a Prime/Not prime statement if its argument is or isn't a prime number. I succeeded using a for loop:

```
def prime1(n):

z = []

for i in range (1, n+1):
    if (n/i).is_integer():
        z.append(i)
        i=i+1

if len(z) == 2:
    print ("Prime")
else:
    print ("Not prime")`
```

Then I tried to do the same but using the while loop:

```
def prime2(n):

z = []
i = 1

while i < int(len(range(1, n+1))):
    if (n/i).is_integer():
        z.append(i)
        i=i+1

if len(z) == 2:
    print ("Prime")
else:
    print ("Not prime")
```

Unfortunately, my system continues to calculating without printing me an output.

Can you explain me where I have made a mistake?

Comment: `if (n/i).is_integer():` if this fails you never increased `i` therefore you are stuck in an infinite loop

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114167/checking-if-a-number-is-a-prime-number-in-python

Comment: The duplicate answers the question "how do you calculate primes numbers?", not the question as asked, which is "why aren't my `while` and `for` loops equivalent?".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `i = i + 1` does nothing in your `for` loop, since the value of `i` is overwritten with the next value of the iterator; effectively, the `for` loop is performing `i = i + 1` for you on *every* iteration, whether or not `i` divides `n`. You need to do the same thing in your `while` loop:

```
while i < n + 1:
    if (n/i).is_integer():
        z.append(i)
    i = i + 1
```

Answer (score 1):

The most pythonic way I could think of is below:

```
def isPrime(n):
    return all(n % i for i in range(2, int(n ** 0.5) + 1)) and n > 1

for i in range(1, 20):
    print(isPrime(i))
```

Explanation:

- all makes sure that every item in the given expression returns `True`
- n % i returns `True` if n != 0 (even negative numbers are allowed)
- `int(n ** 0.5)` is equivalent to `sqrt(n)` and as `range` always returns numbers up to n - 1 you must add 1
- `n > 1` makes sure that `n` is not 1

The problem in your code is that your `i = i + 1` in the wrong scope
Your program checks if `(n/i).is_integer()` which returns `False` as n / 2 is not a integer

Improving your code:

Instead of `(n/i).is_integer()` you can use `n % i == 0`, which returns the remainder equals 0
Next you **must** place `i = i + 1` in the outer scope

And personally, I was never a fan of `i = i + 1`. Use `i += 1`

I think the best way is using the code I have shown above.

Hope this helps!

**Edit:**

You can make it print 'Prime' or 'Not Prime' as follows:

```
def isPrime(n):
    print('Prime' if all(n % i for i in range(2, int(n ** 0.5) + 1))
                 and n > 1 else 'Not Prime')

for i in range(1, 20):
    isPrime(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are increment the iterable variable `i` inside the if statement, so the variable is never incremented, stucking on an infinite loop.

When you used `for` it worked because the iterable changes itself after every full iteration of the block.

Moving the incremenf of `i` one identation block to the left (inside the `while` instead of `for`) will work just fine

Answer (score 0):

Code adapted from https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/examples/prime-number

You don't need to check until num and you can go 2 by 2 if you don't have a database of prime numbers

```
import math
#num = 437
if num > 1:
    # check for factors
    for i in range(2, int(math.ceil(math.sqrt(num))), 2):
        if (num % i) == 0:
            print(num, "is not a prime number")
            print(i, "times", num // i, "is", num)
            break
    else:
        print(num, "is a prime number")

# if input number is less than
# or equal to 1, it is not prime
else:
    print(num, "is not a prime number")
```

Answer (score 0):

Our preferred method should not be `while` loops if we don't need to use them, that being said, we could use list comprehensions:

```
def prime(n):
    z = []  
    [z.append(i) for i in range(1, n+1) if (n/i).is_integer()]
    [print("Prime") if len(z) == 2 else print("Not Prime")]

prime(101)
```

But lets take a loop at what you got your `for` loop:

```
for i in range (1, n+1):
    if (n/i).is_integer():
        z.append(i)
        i=i+1
```

The line `i = i +` doesn't serve the purpose you intend, the loop is going to iterate from `1 to n+1` no matter what

Now the `while` loop:

```
while i < int(len(range(1, n+1))):
   if (n/i).is_integer():
       z.append(i)
       # i=i+1 does not go inside if statement
   i += 1
```

Now you do need to increment `i` but if that incrementing only occurs when the `if` conditions are met, then if the `if` condition is not met you are going to be stuck at the same `i` looping over it.
Also try using  `i += 1` means the same thing