# Loop identifying primes and non-primes generates false output

Tags: python, python-3.x, primes

I am writing code to identify prime and non-prime numbers in a given list.
The idea was to use a nested `for` loop that iterates through the list and checks it against a number in the range of `2` to `n-1`, with `n` being the number to be checked.

Unfortunately the code I come up with, while executing, does not produce the expected output and I seem to be unable to find why.

```py
check_prime = [26, 39, 51, 53, 57, 79, 85]

## write your code here
## HINT: You can use the modulo operator to find a factor

for number in check_prime:
    for x in range (2,number-1):
        if (number %x) ==0:
            print("{} is not a prime because {} is a factor of {}".format(number,x,number))
            break
        elif x  == number-1:
            print ("{} is a prime number".format(number))
```

I'd expect to get an output for every value with either a prime or non-prime statement, but in reality I only get nonprime statements, and even then they are false:

```
26 is not a prime because 2 is a factor of 26
39 is not a prime because 3 is a factor of 39
51 is not a prime because 3 is a factor of 51
57 is not a prime because 3 is a factor of 57
85 is not a prime because 5 is a factor of 85
```

There is obviously an error in my logic, but I can't see it.

Comment: `x  == number-1` never happens in your loop

Comment: yiou could also use a [`for - else`](https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/for_-_else.html) statement to report 'success'... (and checking any further than `math.sqrt(x)` is not necessary...)

Comment: "i only get nonprime statements, and even then they are false" -- all of the "not a prime" statements you show appear to be true.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`x  == number-1` cannot be true because `x` ranges to `number-2` only.

Also, no need to check up to that number, check up to the square root (included) which drastically reduces complexity & computation time in case of huge numbers, and use `else` statement for inner `for` loop, no if no `break` happened, you know that the number is prime:

```
for number in check_prime:
    for x in range (2,int(number**0.5)+1):
        if number % x ==0:
            print("{} is not a prime because {} is a factor of {}".format(number,x,number))
            break
    else:
        print ("{} is a prime number".format(number))
```

That fixes your code. You could read more about this classical prime problem: [Checking if a number is a prime number in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114167/checking-if-a-number-is-a-prime-number-in-python)