# check if integer is a prime, if not return smallest factor

Tags: python, math, primes

I need to check if the given integer is a prime, and return True if so. If not, I need to find the smallest factor which is more than 1. I'm completely new to this and even though code compiles it fails several test cases.

```
def isPrime(n):
  if (n <= 1) : 
    return n
  if (n <= 3) : 
    return 1

if (n % 2 == 0 or n % 3 == 0) : 
    return 2

i = 5
while(i * i <= n) : 
    if (n % i == 0 or n % (i + 2) == 0) : 
        return i
    i = i + 6

return True
```

Comment: Start over from the definition of what a prime is: A number that only can be divided by 1 and itself. You could try to implement [Fermat's little theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat's_little_theorem).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Checking if a number is a prime number in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114167/checking-if-a-number-is-a-prime-number-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

A prime is a number that can only be divided by one and itself. So, if we test `x`, we should test every number `y` such that `1 < y < x`. A good way to test this is to use a for loop. Here is an example:

```
def isPrime(n):
    for i in range(2,n):
        if n % i == 0:
            return False # because that means that something divides into n perfectly
    return True
```

There are a few problems with this:

- `isPrime(1)` returns `True`
- Any negative number will return `True`
- The program gets quite a bit slower as the numbers get bigger. For example, it takes 0.145 seconds to complete `isPrime(1000003)`, but primes take longer to process, because as soon as a factor is found, the entire function stops and returns, whereas for a prime to be found, it has to run through every iteration up to `n`.

I'll leave those problems to you for the moment. In the meantime, we need a way to return the smallest factor. This is actually very easily done:

```
def isPrime(n):
    for i in range(2,n):
        if n % i == 0:
            return i # i at this iteration is equal to the smallest factor
    return True
```

So `isPrime(20)` returns `2`, and `isPrime(19)` returns `True`. Hopefully this satisfies your needs.

Comment: `isPrime(20)` also returns `True`, because 2 evaluates to `True`.

Comment: Are you sure? [Here](https://onlinegdb.com/rJMVJPWzP) is a link to that function online, and it has the output of `2`, which is the lowest factor, excluding 1,of 20. Perhaps you made a formatting error or something when trying to reproduce the above code? Please let me know.

Comment: So you believe that is something is online it must be correct? If you are testing the output of your `isPrime()` method, e.g. `if isPrime(i): print("True")` then both isPrime(20) and isPrime(19) will cause "True" to be printed out.

Comment: No I wrote that function online to show you. But I misread your comment, my apologies. Perhaps instead of returning the lowest factor, it should return `False, i`. It is up to the user to decide, depending on what they need the function to do.

Comment: Yes, that would be an excellent choice, and maybe `True, None` or `True,0` when it's prime.