# My function to filter out prime numbers is printing duplicates, how can I fix this?

Tags: python, function, duplicates

Here is what I have. The function works perfectly fine at filtering out composite numbers, but I can not figure out why it is printing duplicates of certain numbers:

```
def prime_filter(list):
    prime_list = []
    for i in list:
        if i == 2:
            prime_list.append(i)
        if i > 1:
            for n in range(2, i):
                if(i % n == 0):
                    break
                else:
                    prime_list.append(i)
    print("The total number of prime numbers is: ", len(prime_list))
    print(prime_list)
```

Here is my test of the function and the output it returns:

```
# test
test_list = [2, 3, 6, 8, 11]
prime_filter(test_list)

The total number of prime numbers is:  11
[2, 3, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11]
```

Anyone know how I can fix this? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: first thing -> do not use `list` as avariable as its a reserved function in python

Comment: `break` only breaks the inner loop

Comment: remove else part inside for loop

Answer (score 2):

You should check whether prime_list is divided by all the numbers or not.

```
def prime_filter(list):
    prime_list = []
    for i in list:
        if i == 2:
            prime_list.append(i)
        if i > 2:
            for n in range(2, i):
                if(i % n == 0):
                    break
            else:
                prime_list.append(i)
                
    print("The total number of prime numbers is: ", len(prime_list))
    print(prime_list)
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work fine for the solution.`i` should be added to `prime_list` when all the check is done.

```
def prime_filter(list):
    prime_list = []
    for i in list:
        if i == 2:
            prime_list.append(i)
        if i > 1:
            for n in range(2, i):
                if(i % n == 0):
                    break
                if n**2>i:
                    prime_list.append(i)
                    break
    print("The total number of prime numbers is: ", len(prime_list))
    print(prime_list)
```

Comment: This is so called `Sieve of Eratosthenes` algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

in your code for `i>1` for every value of `i` which is odd is getting appended as `odd no%2==1` which makes the program go in `else` part.

also, you only need to add else part when using for loop no value divides the `i`.

here is improved working code

```
def prime_filter(_list):
    prime_list = []
    for i in _list:
        if i == 2:
            prime_list.append(i)
        elif i==1:
            continue
        elif i > 2:
            for n in range(2, i):
                if(i % n == 0):
                    break
            else:
                prime_list.append(i)
    print("The total number of prime numbers is: ", len(prime_list))
    print(prime_list)

test_list = [2, 3, 6, 8, 11]
prime_filter(test_list)
# output [2,3,11]
```

[how to check a no is prime or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114167/checking-if-a-number-is-a-prime-number-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

sahasrara62 and Abhinav answers are, of course, correct, but I would like to point out the bizzare inefficiency here. The biggest factor of composite `n` is at most `sqrt(n)`, which allows to save many iterations at the inner loop.

Another optimization is to avoid checking even factors - we already know the value is odd

```
def prime_filter(lst):
    prime_list = [value for value in lst
                  if (not value % 2 
                      or any(not value % n for n in range(3, value**.5 + 1, 2))
                     )]
```

It can be further improved by adding quick [primality test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller%E2%80%93Rabin_primality_test) before checking factors

Comment: I would've recommended Sieve of Eratosthenes for efficiency. But OP needed to figure out the error rather than improve the speed/complexity of it

Comment: @AbhinavMathur SE is a slightly different thing, it finds all prime numbers less than a given one. Here we are only looking at primality test, which is a different thing.

Comment: Primality testing for a large number of queries becomes much less efficient than SE, it depends on the order of numbers to be tested

Comment: @AbhinavMathur Yep, space vs computational complexity tradeoff. But unlike RAM capacity, CPU time is (potentially) unlimited

Comment: Depends on the usage. If the intended use is for competitive programming, then time is far more important than space in most cases

Comment: @AbhinavMathur good luck handling this case: `lst = [10**10]`

Comment: it's better then mine :D

Comment: I never said SE is the solution to everything. But most such questions are created to use that concept

Comment: @AbhinavMathur You implement algos based on the situation not on whether it is best or not

Answer (score 1):

Your code won't get prime correctly, it will add all numbers not divided by 2, e.g. if there is 9 in the list, it will be included in prime_list. I would like to suggest the following:

```
def prime_filter(list):
prime_list = []
for i in list:
    if i == 2:
        prime_list.append(i)
    if i > 2:
        prime_flag = True
        for n in range(2, i):
            if i % n == 0:
                prime_flag = False
                break

        if prime_flag:
            prime_list.append(i)
print("The total number of prime numbers is: ", len(prime_list))
print(prime_list)
```

test_list = [2, 3, 6, 8, 9, 11]
prime_filter(test_list)

The total number of prime numbers is:  3

[2, 3, 11]

Comment: funfact you can use `else` after `for` loop , as no need to have a check to see if condition satisfied or not

Answer (score 0):

```
else:
    prime_list.append(i)
```

For every factor that doesn't divide `i`, it will be appended to the list, which is incorrect. Just change the function to

```py
def prime_filter(lst):
    prime_list = []
    for i in lst:
        isprime = 1
        if i == 2:
            prime_list.append(i)
        else if i > 1:
            for n in range(2, i):
                if(i % n == 0):
                    isprime = 0
                    break
            if isprime:
                prime_list.append(i)
    print("The total number of prime numbers is: ", len(prime_list))
    print(prime_list)
```