# fizzBuzz numbers 1 to 100: (x3)Fizz, (x5)Buzz, (x3 & x5)FizzBuzz alongwith prime numbers in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, primes, fizzbuzz

**what needs to be corrected in the below code in python?**

e.g 91 is not prime but how it can corrected?

````py
for x in range(100):
    if x%3==0:
       print ("Fizz", x)
    
    elif x%5==0:
      print ("buzz",x)
    
    elif x%3==0 and x%5 == 0:
        
        print ("FizzBuzz",x)

    elif x%x==0 and x%2==1:
       print ("Prime number",x)```
````

Comment: `x % x == 0 and x % 2 == 1` it's not a prime number condition. To get prime number, you must set prime number condition

Comment: @toRex, so what is the right prime number condition which can also work besides with fizz, buzz, fizzbuzz conditions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @toRex mentioned in the comments, you are checking if a number is prime using the condition:

```
x%x==0 and x%2==1
```

Please note that `x%x==0` is always true. So basically you just checking if a number is odd, and print it as a prime. There are many methods to check whether a number is prime or not in general, and specifically in python. For example, you can use [Checking if a number is a prime number in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4114167/2359227) and take the first algorithm from there:

```py
from math import sqrt
from itertools import count, islice

def is_prime(n):
    return n > 1 and all(n % i for i in islice(count(2), int(sqrt(n)-1)))
```

Then call:

```py
for x in range(100):
    if x%3==0 and x%5 == 0:    
        print ("FizzBuzz",x)
    elif x%3==0:
       print ("Fizz", x)
    elif x%5==0:
      print ("buzz",x)
    elif is_prime(x):
       print ("Prime number",x)
```

Will output the expected output. Please also note that I've flipped the order of the conditions, to check first if a number is `FizzBuzz`, and only then if he is a fizz, or a buzz separately. Otherwise a `fizz` number will be considered as a `fizz` and not as a `FizzBuzz` as expected.